# Get multiple select data from Bootstrap Select using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-select

I'm using [bootrap-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzheg.png) plugin

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzheg.png): https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/ I'm trying to grab data from it. I try so many ways but it doesn't work out. So the input is like this:

```
   <div class="col-9">
                                <select id="generals" name="generals" class="form-control kt-selectpicker"  multiple title="Choose one of the following...">
                                <optgroup label="Passport">
                                    <option value="passport_number">Number</option>
                                    <option value="passport_date">Date of issuance</option>
                                    <option value="passport_expired">Date of expiry</option>
                                    <option value="passport_office">Issuing Office</option>
                                </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Personal">
                                        <option value="applicant_id">Applicant Id</option>
                                        <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
                                        <option value="first_name">Middle Name</option>
                                        <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
                                        <option value="address">Address</option>
                                        <option value="crew_id">Crew Id</option>
                                        <option value="email">Email</option>
                                        <option value="mobile_number">Mobile Number</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

I try to grab using PHP foreach and for loops, implode or explode but it doesn't work since it said it does not an array. When i see the Header data sent is like this:
[image]

so how can i get this data? I'm using Ajax to send data. Here's the Fiddle if you want to see it: https://jsfiddle.net/4u6xc9kd/

Comment: create fiddle or running demo.

Comment: ok i will try to create it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18278354/catch-optgroup-label-in-form See if this could help. I'm a little lost. Are you trying to get data after the form is submitted? You can use $_REQUEST or $_POST global variables depending on your case. Can you provide more of the code and clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Mido explode and implode doesn't work either.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4u6xc9kd/

Comment: @Ying can you put ajax code there?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra done i update the fiddle already.

Comment: @Ying there is no jquery ajax code to send data to server in fiddle.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it's here: form.ajaxSubmit({. it work just the same thing as ajax submit.

Comment: you can change it to $.ajax and it will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, you just put the input name like this `name="generals[]"` in your input select and the use foreach like this:

```
    $generals = '';
  if (isset($_POST['generals'])){
      foreach ($_POST['generals'] as $value){
          $generals .= $value . ', ';
      }
  }
```